# string.replace function bug?

Tags: c#, string

```
string s1 = "[quote=useruk1]<p>im useruk1</p>[/quote]<p>hi  im mod1-probe</p>";
string s2 = "hi  im mod1-probe";
string s3 =  "blah blah";
string s4 = s1.Replace(s2, s3);
Console.Write(s4);
```

seems to be not working. Any ideas? How to solve this problem?

UPDATE:

problem was with the space, normal space ASCII value is 32 and above string ASCII value was 160 so i did a

```
s1 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"\u00A0", " ");
```

everthing worked fine ! thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Space versus tab, perhaps?

Comment: A copy of this code in snippet compiler works as expected.

Comment: After Copy/Pasting this code the replacing works fine.

Comment: Strange, it Works on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem was with the space,

normal space ASCII value is 32 and above string ASCII value was 160

so i did a

s1 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"\u00A0", " ");

everthing worked fine !

thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3):

When I run the code, the output is this:

```
[quote=useruk1]<p>im useruk1</p>[/quote]<p>blah blah</p>
```

Isn't that what you'd expect?

Edit: Ah yeah... as Paul points out, space vs. tab would explain it.

Answer (score 3):

Getting output as **`[quote=useruk1]<p>im useruk1</p>[/quote]<p>blah blah</p>`**.

Check the space between **hi** and **im** in "hi  im mod1-probe" in s2 and s1

Answer (score 3):

It does work.  I literally copied this code from your post

```
string s1 = "[quote=useruk1]<p>im useruk1</p>[/quote]<p>hi  im mod1-probe</p>";
string s2 = "hi  im mod1-probe";
string s3 =  "blah blah";
string s4 = s1.Replace( s2, s3 );
Console.Write( s4 );
Console.ReadLine( );
```

and pasted it into a new project.  My result was:

```
"[quote=useruk1]<p>im useruk1</p>[/quote]<p>blah blah</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent any possible misinterpretation of "/p" I would have:

```
string s1 = @"[quote=useruk1]<p>im useruk1</p>[/quote]<p>hi  im mod1-probe</p>";
```